# Accessing Apixu weather API

Tags: python, json

My code is a module to simplify accessing a [weather API](https://www.apixu.com/api.aspx). I'm quite certain it could be simplified, just not sure how yet. Some advice would very much be appreciated. Possibly use individual classes for `day`, `astro`, `condition` etc? I am not quite sure, some advice would be nice.

```
import requests

class Day:
    """Used for finding information on a weekday."""
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.date = data['date']
        day = data['day']
        astro = data['astro']
        condition = day['condition']
        self.maxtemp_c = day['maxtemp_c']
        self.maxtemp_f = day['maxtemp_f']
        self.mintemp_c = day['mintemp_c']
        self.mintemp_f = day['mintemp_f']
        self.avgtemp_c = day['avgtemp_c']
        self.avgtemp_f = day['avgtemp_f']
        self.maxwind_mph = day['maxwind_kph']
        self.totalprecip_mm = day['totalprecip_mm']
        self.totalprecip_in = day['totalprecip_in']
        self.avgvis_km = day['avgvis_km']
        self.avgvis_miles = day['avgvis_miles']
        self.avghumidity = day['avghumidity']
        self.condition_text = condition['text']
        self.condition_icon = condition['icon']
        self.sunrise = astro['sunrise']
        self.sunset = astro['sunset']
        self.moonrise = astro['moonrise']
        self.moonset = astro['moonset']

class CurrentDay:
    """Used for finding information on a current day."""
    def __init__(self, day):
        location = day['location']
        current = day['current']
        condition = current['condition']
        self.location_name = location['name']
        self.location_region = location['region']
        self.location_country = location['country']
        self.location_coords = (location['lat'], location['lon'])
        self.tz_id = location['tz_id']
        self.localtime_epoch = location['localtime_epoch']
        self.localtime = location['localtime']
        self.last_updated_epoch = current['last_updated_epoch']
        self.last_updated = current['last_updated']
        self.temp_c = current['temp_c']
        self.temp_f = current['temp_f']
        self.is_day = current['is_day']
        self.wind_mph = current['wind_mph']
        self.wind_kph = current['wind_kph']
        self.wind_degree = current['wind_degree']
        self.wind_dir = current['wind_dir']
        self.pressure_mb = current['pressure_mb']
        self.pressure_in = current['pressure_in']
        self.precip_mm = current['precip_mm']
        self.precip_in = current['precip_in']
        self.humidity = current['humidity']
        self.cloud = current['cloud']
        self.feelslike_c = current['feelslike_c']
        self.feelslike_f = current['feelslike_f']
        self.vis_km = current['vis_km']
        self.vis_miles = current['vis_miles']
        self.condition_text = condition['text']
        self.condition_icon = condition['icon']




class Weather:
    """Handler"""
    def __init__(self, location, key):
        self.location = location
        self.key = key
        status = requests.get("http://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key={0}&q={1}".format(key, location)).status_code
        if status != 200:
            raise ConnectionError("There was an issue connecting to the weather API!")


    def getForcecast(self, days):
        data = {}
        forecast = requests.get("http://api.apixu.com/v1/forecast.json?key={2}&q={0}&days={1}".format(self.location, days, self.key)).json()

        week = forecast['forecast']['forecastday']
        for day in week:
            date = day['date']
            data[date] = Day(day)
        return data
    def getCurrent(self):
        day = requests.get("http://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key={1}&q={0}".format(self.location, self.key)).json()
        return CurrentDay(day)
```

Comment: Still looking for a bit more organization with it, such as: CurrentDay.Condition.Text or something along those lines.